# Create dataframe from nested dictionaries which contain lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I couldn't find a similar answer to my problem, so here we go:

I have a dict of the following form:

```
d = {key_1: 
        {
         metric_1: [value_11, value_12], 
         metric_2: [value_13, value_14], 
         metric_3: value_15
       }, 
      key_2: {
         metric_1: [value_21], 
         metric_2: [value_22], 
         metric_3: value_23
       }
    }
```

As you can see, metrics do not contain the same number of items in their lists.

What would be a good way to convert this into a df? If I use the `from_dict` method, I end up with df cells that contain lists (bad).

What I am trying to achieve is to have a new row for each one of the values in the lists, keeping the key as index:

```
index | metric_1 | metric_2 | metric_3
———————————————————————————————————————
key_1 | value_11 | value_13 | value_15
key_1 | value_12 | value_14 | value_15
key_2 | value_21 | value_22 | value_23
```

Ideas? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your dataframe has an arbitary length of keys & vals this is one way

```
data_dict = {k : pd.DataFrame(v) for k,v in d.items()}

df = pd.concat(data_dict .values(),keys=data_dict.keys())
```

---

```
print(df)


         metric_1  metric_2  metric_3
key_1 0  value_11  value_13  value_15
      1  value_12  value_14  value_15
key_2 0  value_21  value_22  value_23
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using as I expect to have an arbitrary length of keys and vals. Thanks!

Comment: @gplt you are very welcome, happy coding (don't forget to upvote YO and BEN_W's solution, that man is a genius :))

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way

```
s=pd.DataFrame(d).T
s=s.explode('metric_1').assign(metric_2=s.metric_2.explode().values)
       metric_1  metric_2  metric_3
key_1  value_11  value_13  value_15
key_1  value_12  value_14  value_15
key_2  value_21  value_22  value_23
#s.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as well but I expect the size of the df to change so I ended up using @Datanovice suggestion below.